# Django CSRF Cookie -- why doesn't it expire at browser close?

Tags: django, csrf

Django allows you to specify that the session expires at browser close (with some caveats for Chrome). Why doesn't it do that for the CSRF cookie?

I ask because it seems to me that the CSRF token is vulnerable to being leaked (e.g., by mistakenly putting it in a post to an external site), and this would be a mitigation for that. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll repost my answer from the developer's list that Carl linked, so that stackoverflow has it too:

> If the cookie were set to expire at browser close, it would cause CSRF 
>   errors for users who closed a browser (or bookmarked a page with a 
>   form on it) and then loaded that page from a browser cache and 
>   submitted the form. I'm ambivalent about whether this use case is 
>   worth supporting (it may be important on mobile devices, for example), 
>   but I don't believe that setting the cookie to expire on browser close 
>   provides much security benefit to an otherwise properly configured 
>   site (HTTPS, HSTS, etc.).
>
> Django's CSRF implementation differs[1] from many others which store 
>   CSRF information alongside session information on the server. The CSRF 
>   mechanism functions by matching a token provided in a form with a 
>   token provided as a cookie in the browser. If you set the cookie to 
>   'zzz', it will still function perfectly well. The security comes from 
>   the fact that an attacker cannot set the cookie, not that it happens 
>   to contain any specific cryptographic value.
>
> If the concern is that an attacker could access a user's physical 
>   computer between sessions and steal a CSRF token, setting it to expire 
>   at browser close would not prevent an attacker from inserting a cookie 
>   of known value that would be used during the next session. I'm not 
>   convinced we can secure the tokens of a user whose computer has been 
>   physically accessed by an attacker.
>
> Still, if it can be convincingly demonstrated that setting the cookie 
>   to expire at browser close would not break existing use cases (mobile 
>   browsers are my chief concern) I'd be open to changing the default 
>   behavior. We generally consider it a bug if any non-malicious user 
>   can, through innocent behavior, trigger the CSRF warning.
>
> [1] Django's CSRF implementation usually sets off all kinds of false 
>   alarms in most pen-tester tools, since it doesn't work exactly the 
>   same way other implementations do, and isn't tied to the session 
>   cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question isn't really about the attacker accessing the user's physical computer, but mitigating potential leaks of the CSRF token. I don't see any mitigation here.

Comment: If you've got ideas about ways it might be possible to leak the CSRF token accidentally, I'd like to hear about them via email. Aside from deliberately bad code (posting a CSRF protected form to another site, or allowing users to create such forms, or control post targets), I'm not aware of anything like that.

Comment: I'm curious about the case where a user is on a public computer. Unless I am misunderstanding this entire process, couldn't an attacker hop onto a public computer and grab the token, then attempt to trick someone using that same terminal? At that point the attacker would have the csrftoken (since it doesn't expire on close and is session independent), and crafting a request is easy. How can we prevent this in the case I'm not missing something simple?

Comment: Disregard my last comment - I was developing with a beta version of Django that must have had this feature disabled. Upgrading to the release version of 1.6 re-enables the changing csrf token on each new session.