# CSRF token's value not changing in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am a new to the Django framework.

I have created a simple arithmetic application using django.

As suggested in the django documentation, I wrote

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

in my template file.

But, the thing i notice is that,
token value is not changing on post request.

It is showing same value every time with expiry of 364 days

> So, let me know the settings to change CSRF Token Value in each post request.

Thanks in advance

> My template code below

```
    <form action="{{ action }}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
            <legend>{{ tag }}:</legend>
            Number 1: <input type="text" size="10" name="num1" value="{{ n1|default:0 }}"><br>
            <span> {{ operator }} </span><br>
            Number 2: <input type="text" size="10" name="num2" value="{{ n2|default:0 }}"><br>
            <span> = </span><br>
            Result&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <input type="text" size="10" value="{{ res|default:0 }}" disabled>
            &nbsp; <span>{{ warning|default:'' }} </span><br><br>
            <input type="submit" size="10">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <a href="/app1">App1 Home</a>
```

> My view code below

```
def add(request):
    warn = ''
    res, n1, n2 = (0, 0, 0)

    try:
        n1 = int(request.POST['num1'])
        n2 = int(request.POST['num2'])
        res = n1 + n2
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        warn = 'Text data is not allowed.'

    params = {'operator': '+', 'action': 'add', 'tag': 'Addition' ,'n1': n1, 'n2': n2, 'res': res, 'warning': warn}
    return render(request, 'arithmatic_app1.html', params)
```

Comment: CSRF in django are tied to the user login session([create by the session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30539335/11225821)), when a user log out or their login session end(duration of a session can be changed) the token will change the next time user login, as for changing CSRF expire duration it's not recommend as stated by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19186747/11225821)

Comment: I found this answer useful regarding the RequestContext. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691647/django-csrf-requestcontext